# Make two date fields with same name in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am building joomla component so in admin part, I am doing muliple addition of records e.g.
if I press on add two new textbox with Joomla date field created with same name and so on. But datepicker is working on first two boxes its not working in newly created boxes.

this is the sample code datepicker is working on these two:

Start Date:

End Date:

so if i press add new it creates other two boxes with same name and datepicker is not working in those.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show some of the code you have used. Hard to tell what the problem is without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datepicker is a javascript library, you need to invoke it (it's not attached to the dom elements themselves, it gets loaded by a script like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {Calendar.setup({
                ...
```

which you should invoke after duplicating the fields. This comes from com_content (administrator, where you edit an article); however at a minimum in another component you will want to have, after creating a new date field with id: **jform_date_id_1**

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField: "jform_date_id_1",
    ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
//  button: "jform_created_img",
    align: "Tl",
    singleClick: true,
    firstDay: 1
});
```

make sure you adjust the options according to your needs.  Since these come from the backend components, it may be wise to prepare the options object from php, and just edit the inputField at runtime if you want to have correct localization.